# HTML div navigation

Tags: html, navigation

I`ve seen on various websites, some links appear like this: `http://www.myserver.com/page.html#something` and when I click on it, it just moves to another portion of the page.

I want to know how to do this. Is it only the URL of the `<a href>` atrribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment at the end of the url coresponds to an ID on the page you're visiting.

If in my page I have a section such as:

```
<div id="comments">
...
</div>
```

Then I can take the user to this section by attaching `#comments` to the pages URL

(http://www.example.com/page.html#comments)

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/page.html#comments">Link to comments</a>
```

**Update**

Some of the other answers here correctly point out that you can create an anchor with a name attribute as: `<a name="example"></a>`.

Although this is technically correct, it's also a very antiquated way of doing things and something I'd recommend you avoid. It's very 1997 as some might say :-)

Answer (score 2):

The text after the hashtag corresponts with an anchor on the page. An anchor is a hidden element on the page which you can link to.

Think for example about a large page with an to top link in it

To create an anchor use:

```
<a name="C4"></a>
```

To link to it use: `<a href="#C4">Text</a>`

Or you can even link to an id of an element

Answer (score 1):

Check out: [links](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm) (aka anchors)

Also note that you can use `<a name="something"></a>` or `<a id="something"></a>`

or using divs `<div id="something"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to a bookmark on the given page (or even just #something on the current page).

To make it work, you need to define something. You can do this using the name attribute of an `<a>` tag.

http://programming.top54u.com/post/HTML-Anchor-Bookmark-Tag-Links.aspx